# "npx playwright test" gives an error in cmd

Tags: playwright

This is my file path `C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\tests` to the `example.spec.ts` file. Below is the sample code generated by playwright:

```javascript
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);
});

test('get started link', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Click the get started link.
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Get started' }).click();

  // Expects page to have a heading with the name of Installation.
  await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Installation' })).toBeVisible();
});
```

When run the command `npx playwright test` getting below error:

```
Error: No tests found
Error in reporter Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\playwright-report'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1386:3)
    at new HtmlBuilder (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\reporters\html.js:198:17)
    at HtmlReporter.onEnd (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\reporters\html.js:101:21)
    at wrapAsync (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\reporters\multiplexer.js:79:12)
    at Multiplexer.onEnd (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\reporters\multiplexer.js:51:25)
    at InternalReporter.onEnd (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\reporters\internalReporter.js:69:12)
    at Runner.runAllTests (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\runner\runner.js:84:28)
    at runTests (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\program.js:180:93)
    at t.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\node_modules\playwright\lib\program.js:53:7) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\PlaywrightAutomation\\playwright-report'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: check the config file for testDir

Comment: Where are you running `npx playwright test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should start by making sure you have the necessary required write permissions to create directories in `C:\Users\User\PlaywrightAutomation\`. That's where the `mkdir : EPERM: operation not permitted` come from.

For the tests not found, a path variable **testDir** has to be specified in the file `playwright.config.ts` :

```
import { defineConfig} from '@playwright/test';
/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  // The rest of the basic config
});
```

Make sure you well cloned all the required file from the documentation git project in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much @Thom omega. 'testDir:' was wrong in my 'playwright.config.ts' file.